# Highlight pixels in difference image of two images where pixels are not equal

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing

I have two images which are similar. I would like to highlight the pixels in the difference image (e.g. in red) if the values are not exactly 0.

How can I do that? I know I can get the image data with `ImageData[image,...]` and then I can caluclate the differences. But how do I find the non equal pixels and colorize them?

img1
[image]

img2
[image]

Comment: The two images are exactly same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Binarize[ImageDifference[img1, img2], 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
ImageDifference[img1, img2] // ImageAdjust
```